# Laravel: Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm updating to Laravel 5.4 and am receiving the following error message when trying to display the login screen.

I'm receiving the following error message:

> Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found

Here's is the AuthController class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Where to redirect users after logout.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/login';

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => ['getLogout']]);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

with laravel 5.4 we have some changes in this trait. Now we have two different traits:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
```

And if you install a fresh 5.4 laravel application you will see that now you have LoginController and RegisterController instead of AuthController

Comment: Is there any way I can get the authenticated user in the trait.?

Answer (score 23):

If you're in Laravel 7+, you'll need to first install the `laravel/ui` package (since this contains auth backend code) by running the following command:

```
$composer require laravel/ui
```

and then

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now! But I don't know why they are related!! laravel/ui just supposed to create UI scaffolding

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki looks like the repo contains all the *backend* logic for the *UI* provided by the [package](https://github.com/laravel/ui/tree/2.x/auth-backend).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use this trait instead

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're migrating to Laravel 8.x consider moving your authentication layer to [Laravel Breeze](https://github.com/laravel/breeze):

```
$ composer require laravel/breeze --dev
$ php artisan breeze:install
```

See [Starter Kits](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits) for more details.