# Laravel getting error when Upgraded to higher version

Tags: php, laravel

I upgraded my laravel application from 5.2 to 5.5 I am getting this error:

```
"Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found"
```

I am using php 7.1.2 I am getting this error.

My composer json file is:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.2",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
},
```

I am using this inside authcontroller.php:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
```

But I am getting error I used this answer but it is not clear.

[Suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788861/laravel-trait-illuminate-foundation-auth-authenticatesandregistersusers-not-f)

I am using these traits in auth controller:

```
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\UserActivity1;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
```

Comment: What traits are you using in `AuthController`

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guides from 5.2 -> 5.3 -> 5.4 -> 5.5?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788861/laravel-trait-illuminate-foundation-auth-authenticatesandregistersusers-not-f)

Comment: I used solution provided here I mentioned it in my question

Comment: Since Laravel 5.4 you have to use `LoginController` and `RegisterController` instead of `AuthController`. But better follow all upgrade guides